# Select text (almost) next to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, jquery-selectors

I need to wrap a radio button and the text next to it in a label, just to be more user-friendly.

I had a similar problem a few days ago, where I have a checkbox and immediately after I had a span element. And I could wrap both elements.

I have this HTML:

```
<span class="Attribute">
    <input type="radio" name="vMONHRDREM" value="S">
    <script type="text/javascript">gx.dom.setAttribute("vMONHRDREM","gxoch0","if(!(gx.evt.jsEvent(this))) return false;");</script>
    Ativado

    <input type="radio" name="vMONHRDREM" value="N">
    <script type="text/javascript">gx.dom.setAttribute("vMONHRDREM","gxoch0","if(!(gx.evt.jsEvent(this))) return false;");</script>
    Desativado
</span>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the HTML structure as I use a tool that generates the pages.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
    alert($(this).next().next().text());
});
```

But it's not working. It doesn't return anything. If I change to `$(this).next().text()` I get the script text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input elements don't have text content, what you have is rogue textnodes, and you'll need to target those together with the inputs, and then wrap them with label tags:

```
$('.Attribute input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    $(this).addBack()
           .add($(this).next('script')[0].nextSibling)
           .wrapAll('<label></label>');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h87cf/1/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).next().get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
});
```

Comment: great! this show me the values. but how can wrap both elements? If I use ...nextSibling.wrap("<label />"). it even wrap just the "text node".